# joinChannelWithUserAccount throws error `Request is refused` intermittently

Tags: react-native, agora.io

Using Agora SDK  "react-native-agora": "^3.1.6". Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Can you describe how to reproduce the error?

Comment: Found the route cause. It happens when you join another channels without leaving the current one.

Answer (score 0):

You should leave channel first using this function before join other channel

```
_engine?.leaveChannel();
```